# Time specified in dhclient.leases file is several years in the future

Tags: linux, dhclient

**Background**

Several embedded linux devices are connected via ethernet to a network. Based on what port they are plugged into on the switch they get a corresponding DHCP IP address (each port exists on a separate VLAN). After acquiring a DHCP address the devices can then contact all other services (NTP, ftp servers etc.). The devices are non-unique and any device should be able to be plugged into any port (i.e. cannot use static IPs). The dhclient.leases files are updated to reflect the new lease that is provided every 30 seconds.

**Issue**

If the devices are power cycled normally they retain their system time; however, in some case all devices will be powered off for a long period of time and the embedded Linux system will lose its system time. In this scenario, the time reverts to 01/01/2011. Our theory on what happening is that the expiry time in the dhclient.leases file is in the future (as it was acquired when the system time was correct) and so the unit will not allow another DHCP address to be acquired. And as it cannot get an address it cannot get an NTP time to update the system time and hence we enter a chicken and egg scenario. The way we can sometimes fix this it to continuously reset the unit until eventually it acquires a lease.

**Questions**

1. Is this the expected behaviour of dhclient?
2. If the answer to 1. is *no*, what could be causing the units to not acquire a DHCP address after a long power off period?
3. Are there any suggested fixes, work arounds or configuration changes that would be suggested to help with the issue?

Comment: Raspberry Pi systems handle this to some extent by setting the time at boot to be the time recorded at shutdown. It's still wrong, but less so